# SQL update inner join not working in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

```
UPDATE  d
set d.tSynchronized = 1
from TImageRaw d
inner join TPatientRaw f
on f.tPatCulIntPatIDPk = d.tImgCulIntPatIDFk
```

The code above is not work in SQL Server, can someone point me the right direction ?

Comment: Define "is not work" - is there an error?  If so, what is the message?

Comment: Only the tSynchronized is being changed on TImageRaw and you're expecting it to be changed in both TImageRaw and TPatientRaw?

Answer (score 2):

Your `UPDATE` structure looks fine at first glance. Since you have not stated the error, here are some probable causes:

- You misspelled some table name
- You misspelled some column name
- `f.tPatCulIntPatIDPk` and `d.tImgCulIntPatIDFk` do not have compatible types
- `d.tSynchronized` is not a numeric typed field

Comment: The other possiblity is that it is updating the wrong records, in which case the OP probably needs a where clause of some type.